# How can I build a custom text-area control with support for immutable placeholders?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a very simple rich-text editor for customers of my product to customize emails that are sent. An email is mostly just plain text, but it also has the ability to have placeholders - such as "Dear `username`". Rather than have my users learn some sort of custom syntax to mention placeholders (I want to avoid having them feel like they are doing anything that remotely resembles programming), I would like them to be able to click buttons for the placeholders, at which point the placeholder will be inserted inline into the text area.

If this seems confusing, the closest similarity I can think of is in Facebook or Google+. Both Facebook and Google+ feature a "status" text area where people can share a short amount of mostly-unformatted text. In this text area, they can also tag friends - at which point a new immutable object is added to the text area. People are free to edit text around this object, and it will be moved appropriately.

I'm unsure how to build such a control. My first attempts were to use `contenteditable`, but that seems riddled with cross-browser incompatibilities, and generally a road of pain.

What would people advise to build such a feature?

Comment: You shouldn't ask for "Facebook status editor", but for the exact feature you're after: inline boxes in textareas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will amend my question now.

Comment: Also, asking for libraries is off-topic on SO; better ask for *how* to implement such a feature.

Comment: Question updated, hopefully that's a better question now.